# can anyone tell me what is the logical error in the below gibs sampling code?

Tags: python-3.x, sampling, lda

I stuck in the implementation of LDA gibs sampling code. Below the code is a snippets of my actual LDA gibs-sampling code. but i think there is some logical error in the my implementation and i don't know what is error actually.

**Here is the code**

```
class LDAGibbs:
    def __init__(self, num_topics, doc_file_path, vocas, output_dir_name, alpha=0.1, beta=0.01):
        """
        Constructor method
        Do not modify this function.
        :param num_topics: the number of topics
        :param doc_file_path: BOW document file path
        :param vocas: vocabulary list
        :param output_dir_name: output directory name
        :param alpha: alpha value in LDA
        :param beta: beta value in LDA
        :return: void
        """
        self.docs = self.read_bow(doc_file_path)
        self.words = vocas
        self.K = num_topics
        self.D = len(self.docs)
        self.W = len(vocas)
        self.output_dir_name = output_dir_name

        # Hyper-parameters
        # We use symmetric hyper-parameters
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.beta = beta

        # self.WK: Words by Topics matrix
        # self.DK: Documents by Topics matrix
        self.WK = np.zeros([self.W, self.K])
        self.DK = np.zeros([self.D, self.K])

        # Random initialization of topics
        np.random.seed(108)
        # Topic index of each word in each document
        self.doc_topics = list()

        for di in range(self.D):
            doc = self.docs[di]
            topics = np.random.randint(self.K, size=len(doc))
            self.doc_topics.append(topics)

            for wi in range(len(doc)):
                topic = topics[wi]
                word = doc[wi]
                self.WK[word, topic] += 1
                self.DK[di, topic] += 1

    def run(self, max_iter=2000, do_print_log=False):
        """
        Run Collapsed Gibbs sampling for LDA
        Do not modify this function.
        :param max_iter: Maximum number of Gibbs sampling iterations
        :param do_print_log: Print loglikelihood and run time
        :return: void
        """
        if do_print_log:
            prev = time.clock()
            for iteration in range(max_iter):
                print(iteration, time.clock() - prev, self.loglikelihood())
                prev = time.clock()
                self._gibbs_sampling()
                if iteration % 100 == 99:
                    self.export_result(output_file_name="iter_{}".format(iteration))
        else:
            for iteration in range(max_iter):
                self._gibbs_sampling()
                if iteration % 100 == 99:
                    self.export_result(output_file_name="iter_{}".format(iteration))

    def _gibbs_sampling(self):
        for di in range(self.D):
            doc = self.docs[di]
            for wi in range(len(doc)):
                word = doc[wi]

                old_topic = self.doc_topics[di][wi]
                self.DK[di, old_topic] -= 1
                self.WK[word, old_topic] -= 1

                prob_vec = self.DK[di] + self.alpha
                prob_item = self.WK[word] + self.beta
                prob_vec /= np.sum(self.WK + self.beta, axis=0)
                new_topic = self._sampling_from_dist(prob_vec)

                self.doc_topics[di][wi] = new_topic
                self.DK[di, new_topic] += 1
                self.WK[word, new_topic] += 1
```

I want to implement LDA gibs sampling on my own but my result is different from actual gibs sampling. I think in the _gibbs_sampling function there is some implementation error. Can you tell me what is the problem in the above code?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [SO] is not a debugging services. The following references give advice on ydebugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.